# Как в JS правильно обращаться к свойству объекта, если его значение есть только в строчном типе данных?

Tags: javascript

В HTML есть несколько `<select/>`, по изменению `<option/>` которых, через `someFunction()` передаётся значение:

```
<select onchange="someFunction('item1')"></select>
<select onchange="someFunction('item2')"></select>
```

В функции `someFunction()` происходит обращение к свойству объекта `someObject`:

```
function someFunction(selectNumber) {

    let someData = someObject.selectNumber;

    // много-много преобразований данных

}
```

В объекте `someObject` данные сгруппированы по селектам: первому селекту соответствуют `someObject.item1`, второму - `someObject.item2`:

```
let someObject = {
    'item1': {
        // много-много вложенных данных
    },
    'item2': {
        // много-много вложенных данных
    },
}
```

Но такая запись не работает, поскольку `selectNumber` - строчный:

```
let someData = someObject.selectNumber;
```

**Вопрос:**

- как в `someFunction()` нужно преобразовать передаваемый в неё параметр и / или
- какие типы данных должны быть у свойств `someObject`

чтобы в переменную `someData` попали данные из `someObject.item1` или `someObject.item2`?

Конечно, можно решить задачу через условие, где-то следующим образом:

```
function someFunction(selectNumber) {

    if (selectNumber === 'item1') {
        let someData = someObject.item1
    } else if (selectNumber === 'item2') {
        let someData = someObject.item2
    }

    // много-много преобразований данных

}
```

Но явно же решение не изящное и не профессиональное.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, нужно всего лишь использовать скобочную нотацию: `let someData = someObject[selectNumber]`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, дякую. Можете ответ написать, чтобы я проплюсовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать [скобочную нотацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```js
function someFunction(selectNumber) {

    let someData = someObject[selectNumber];

    // много-много преобразований данных
}
```